# Stop default web site by powershell

Tags: iis-7, powershell

I stop default web site by powershell and it's stopped. But I find it started after reboot.

If I stop it manually in IIS7 manager, it will be stopped after rebooting machine.

It looks like stopping website by powershell is not so efficient.

anybody has any idea about it?

OS: Windows 2008 R2 SP1
IIS: 7

Comment: Keith Hill has good point about this problem. Powershell uses stop function only to change state of website to stopped, but it will be started after reboot or iisreset. Now the problem is how to change serverAutoStart property of website to false in Powershell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current state and the "startup" state are two different controllable entities just as they are in the IIS Manager GUI.  Set the startup state to Manual or Disabled like so:

```
Set-Service w3svc -StartupType Manual
```

Update: If you only want to affect the startup of one on several sites then try this:

```
PS> ipmo WebAdministration
PS> Get-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' ServerAutoStart


PSPath                      : WebAdministration::\\HILLR1\Sites\Default Web Site
PSParentPath                : WebAdministration::\\HILLR1\Sites
PSChildName                 : Default Web Site
PSDrive                     : IIS
PSProvider                  : WebAdministration
IsInheritedFromDefaultValue : False
IsProtected                 : False
Name                        : serverAutoStart
TypeName                    : System.Boolean
Schema                      : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttributeSchema
Value                       : True
IsExtended                  : False

PS> Set-ItemProperty 'IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site' ServerAutoStart False
```

Comment: the syntax should be Set-Service w3svc -StartupType manual. But this will prevent start website in powershell.

Comment: Thank you. Fingers were typing away while brain was apparently engaged in other things.  :-)

Comment: Please note @Xenophane's answer: the property name "serverAutoStart" is case-sensitive. I just tried on Server 2016, and it didn't work until I got the case right.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to do this on Server 2012R2 ServerAutoStart is serverAutoStart (notice the lowercase "s" in serverAutoStart

Hooray for case sensitivity  :)